# get the text of the selected option using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

in the following:

```
<form  action="test.php"  method="POST">  
    <select id="test" name="test">
     <option value="1">Test One</option>
     <option value="2">Test Two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

in test.php, I can get 1 or 2 as follow:

```
$result=$_POST['test'];
```

How can I get the text of the selected option (i.e. "Test One" or "Test Two") using php

Comment: If you want the text, why not make the text the value?

Comment: Would you mind naming the specifics of the situation (ie Why you need both)? Maybe we can brainstorm a solution.

Comment: If you want to use the 1 and 2 value in JavaScript you can assign it to a different attribute such as title, alt, or anything you want.

Comment: I assume it's a typo, but your `select` element is missing its (mandatory) `name` attribute, which should be `id` (after your update it should be `test`).

Comment: We can give you all the possibilities you want, but until you tell us what you are truly trying to accomplish by passing both values, nobody can give you the best answer possible.

Comment: @powerbuoy -  Good catch. If the user is able to access it in the POST array he must have just missed it when typing up the question (i've updated it).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not something that can be done through PHP alone. The PHP script can only "see" the information which is posted (the `value` for the `selected` option that is posted). You can use javascript to alter a hidden `input` field with the text contents of a selected `option`, and this will be included in the `$_POST` array:

```
<form  action="test.php"  method="POST">  
    <select id="test" onchange="document.getElementById('text_content').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
     <option value="1">Test One</option>
     <option value="2">Test Two</option>
    </select>

<input type="hidden" name="test_text" id="text_content" value="" />
</form>
```

This will make the `$_POST['test_text']` available with the selected index (but you should also force the `onchange()` function when the page loads so that it will be populated even if the user leaves the select field at the default value.

Comment: And how does this work for devices which do not support JS?

Comment: @powerbuoy - it doesn't. It's a rare issue these days, but yours is the better solution (+1)

Answer (score 17):

Only the `value` of the form control will be sent to the server. An easy way to send both is to simply *include both* in the the `value`:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1|Test one">Test one</option>
    <option value="2|Test two">Test two</option>
</select>
```

And then:

```
$test = explode('|', $_POST['test']);
```

Then you'll end up with `$test[0]` being "1" and `$test[1]` being "Test one".

Comment: I tried and works also very well

Answer (score 3):

You can't; that information is not sent back to the server. You will need to look at how you generated the HTML in the first place and get the text from there.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sent so the only way to get it is having an array mapping values to titles in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I could use except I already have the onChange calling a function to show a hidden  block based on the selected building type in a  statement.

I have building types I need the user to select.  Several building types have a unique set of questions, e.g. Bank Branch, Data Center, Courtroom, etc.  But there are many that have the same set of questions which I call Other Type.  Each option has their associated value, e.g. Bank Branch has a value of "Bank_Branch", Data Center has "Data_Center", but Other Type has a value of "Other_Type".  The text for "Other_Type" differs based on the building type, such as Convention Center, Museum, Performing Arts, etc.  So I need the value "Other_Type" to "show" the questions in the "Other_Type" DIV block while using the text value to send in an email identifying the type of building, e.g. Convention Center, Museum, Performing Arts, etc.

Any way to use PHP to get the text value of the selected item?  I'm already using the following inside the HTML

```
   var sele = document.getElementById('building_type');
   var seleVal = sele.options[sele.selectedIndex].value;
   var seleTxt = sele.options[sele.selectedIndex].text;
   document.getElementById("other_text").innerHTML = seleTxt;
```

I'm not seeing a way to do this.

SOLVED:  I can simply create the hidden div and in my check for Other Type set the innerHTML for the hidden div.

Comment: I spoke too soon:

I added:
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_text" name="hidden_text" value="">

Then set document.getElementById("hidden_text").value = seleTxt;

If I make the "hidden_text" filed visible the value I want is there.  But when I try to use it, $_POST['hidden_text'] is empty.

Any ideas why $_POST['hidden_text'] would be empty?

Answer (score 0):

The text for the selected option is not passed through the HTML form.  If you want the text, you have to store that in a hidden HTML input on your page, or you need to add some business logic in your PHP code to translate the value of `ìd` into the text (through a switch statement, or by querying a database, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when you submit a form and a variable it only takes one parameter which is it's value. You would need to make the value. Test One the value in order for it to pass on to the PHP script. What is the purpose of value="1" cause you can probably use it in a different attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Im not a experienced php programer, but u can check the value selected in SELECT tag with php.
i dont know why people say u can not.

```
if ( $_POST['test'] == 1) 
{ do something } 
else 
{ option value 2 is selected, do something else }
```

Im sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it if 1, 2 not needed. you will get required text as value

```
<form  action="test.php"  method="POST">  
    <select id="test" name="test">
     <option value="Test One">Test One</option>
     <option value="Test Two">Test Two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```