# Dropdown Select Getting Text Value instead of the assined value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm just wondering if this is possible, supposed I have:

```
<select name = 'region' id = 'region'>
  <option value = '1'>Region 1</option>
<select>
```

Now, I know I get the value of 1 when I select "Region 1". Is there a way to get
the "Region 1" as the value itself without changing the value = '1'. I need that for javascript for other dropdowns.

Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm referring to PHP. I know that:

```
$value = $_POST['region'];
```

will the value of 1, how can I get just the text to pass on $_POST?

Comment: you want to do this in backend?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926906/get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-using-php

Comment: I forgot to mention, in php?

Comment: In php? how about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926906/get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-using-php

Comment: Why dont you keep the value of the option equal to 'Region 1' ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.getElementById('region');
var text = el.selectedIndex == -1 ? null : el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross Browser:

```
var select = document.getElementById('region');
if(select.addEventListener) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {     
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        var selected = target[target.selectedIndex];
        var text = selected.textContent || selected.innerText;
        alert(text);
    });
 }
else if(select.attachEvent) {
  select.attachEvent('onchange', function(evt) {
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        var selected = target[target.selectedIndex];
        var text = selected.textContent || selected.innerText;
        alert(text);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LrETq/

Comment: I prefer your example over the other ones. Just one thing to note:  `textContent` isn't compatible with all browsers, some of them (IE8) support `innerText` instead.

Comment: @W.D thank you. Good point. I changed it check for at least one of them.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please correct your `innerText` and change it to `selected.innerText`? And I think `event.target || event.srcElement` will do it, no need for `event.originalTarget`.

Comment: Just did. You know what I just realized a way shorter way to do this: `this[this.selectedIndex].innerText || this[this.selectedIndex].textContent;` When would that not be the best to do it?

Comment: Using `this` with `.addEventListsner` isn't a good idea. IE8 won't recognize `this`. Besides, `.addEventListsner` isn't supported in IE8 as well, you may want to use `.attachEvent` instead. And one last 'remark' (: - change `var selected = event.target` to `var selected = target`.

Comment: Yes, forgot to do that. Updated the fiddle.

Comment: And `event` isn't supported in `Firefox`, change it to `evt = event || window.event; var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var value1 = document.getElementById("region");
var value2 = value1.options[value1.selectedIndex].text;
alert(value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

js

```
$("#region").change(function(){
  var domNode = document.getElementById("region");
  var value = domNode.selectedIndex;
  var selected_text = domNode.options[value].text;
  alert(selected_text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you haven't mentioned whether you are planning on supporting legacy browsers or not, I've decided to add support for that browsers as well. My script works with all IE versions (IE7 inclusive).

So, first we attach our `eventlistener` to your `select` element. Then we retrieve the text of the selected option and return the value;

Have a look at this => <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hrBLr/9/)**</kbd>

If you want to submit it via `$_POST` than do the following ->

1. Create a `hidden` `input` element, set its name attribute to say `select`, then set its value to the value of our `text` variable (we will have that variable when one of our options is selected) - See the code below.
2. After submitting your form you can retrieve the value like so => `$_POST['select']` (`select` is the `name` `attribute` we have assigned to our `hidden input` element)

**Javascript**

```
//attaching the eventlistener (modified the code to make it compatible with older IE versions)

function attach(element,listener,ev,tf){

    if(element.attachEvent) {

        //support for older IE (IE7 inclusive)
        element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);

        }else{

        //modern browsers
        element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);

        }

    }

function returnTextofTheSelectedElement(sel){

    //getting and returning the text of the selected option
    selectedIndex = sel[sel.selectedIndex];
    return text = selectedIndex.innerText ? selectedIndex.innerText : selectedIndex.textContent;

    }

var select = document.getElementById('region');

attach(select,'change',function(){

    //pass the select tag you want to get the text of
    //*returnTextofTheSelectedElement* function returns our text
    alert(returnTextofTheSelectedElement(select));

    //so you can store it in a *variable* and use it when submitting your form
    text = returnTextofTheSelectedElement(select);

    //if you want to submit it via $_POST than do the following
    //create a hidden *input* element, set its name attribute to say *select*, then set its value to the value of our *text* variable

    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = 'select';
    input.value = text;

    select.parentNode.appendChild(input);

    alert('The value/text of the hidden input is '+input.value);

    //when submitting the form, it will also submit out hidden input with the value (text) of the selected option
    //you can retrieve the value like so => *$_POST['select']* 


},false);
```

**HTML**

```
<select name='region' id='region'>

    <option value='1'>Region 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Region 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Region 3</option>

<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(select#region option).click(function(){

          var textOfTheSelectedOption= $(this).text();
          alert( textOfTheSelectedOption);

});
```

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about jQuery in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get text value like this. Is it helpful?

```
var e = document.getElementById("region");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(value);
```

Comment: My apology, I forgot to mention it is in php. see my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function getSelectedText(){
   var theSelect= document.getElementById("region");
var theText= theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text;
alert(theText);

}
</script>
<select name = 'region' id = 'region'  onchange="getSelectedText()">
  <option value = '1'>Region 1</option>
  <option value = '2'>Region 2</option>

<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<select name = 'region' id = 'region'  onchange="fnc()">
  <option value = '1'>Region 1</option>
  <option value = '2'>Region 2</option>
<select>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_region" id="hidden_region">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(){
var el = document.getElementById('region');
var text = el.selectedIndex == -1 ? '' : el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById('hidden_region').value = text;
}
</script>
```

in php post will be like

```
$value = $_POST['hidden_region'];
```