# Getting the HTML display and not value in PHP

Tags: php, html, email, post

I have these lines of code.

```
<select id="select12" name="package">
    <option value="0.00">(Select a Package)</option>
    <option value="149.00">PACKAGE A</option>
    <option value="223.00">PACKAGE B</option>
    <option value="273.00">PACKAGE C</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the "Package A/B/C" and its value. For example if the user selects the Package A. The output is Package A - $149.00. How will I do that? This is the code I have so far in achieving that getting the HTML, but it is no luck.

```
$package = $_POST['package'];

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {

        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }
 $email_message .= "Selected Package: ".clean_string($package)."\n";
```

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11926913/2518525)

Comment: you need js to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$_POST['package']` will give you value (e.g. 149, 223 etc) and add a hidden textbox and assign select text (e.g. Package A etc) by doing: `$( "#select12 option:selected" ).text();` and send that data.

See, if that helps.

Comment: Visit: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest thing that you can do is:

```
<select id="select12" name="package">
    <option value="0.00">(Select a Package)</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE A - $149.00">PACKAGE A</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE B - $223.00">PACKAGE B</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE C - $273.00">PACKAGE C</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

For integer value you can use:

```
preg_match('!\d.+!', $package, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: I used the numerical values to add to other parts of the code, so I wouldn't want t do that...

Comment: @Darren because it will return an empty space and a `$` sign with the numerical part. then we will need to trim it. So its better we use `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

How about simply modify your form like this :

```
<select id="select12" name="package">
    <option value="0.00">(Select a Package)</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE A - $149.00">PACKAGE A</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE B - $223.00">PACKAGE B</option>
    <option value="PACKAGE C - $273.00">PACKAGE C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you just copy-paste the other answer or what?

Comment: Why I should do that. We simply post it at near same time. Just look at how close the time is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#select12').change(function(){
            var this_val=$(this).val();
            if(this_val!='0.00')
            {
                var this_html=$( "#select12 option:selected" ).text();
                $('#result').html(this_html+' - $'+this_val);
            }
       });
    });
</script>


<select id="select12" name="package">
    <option value="0.00">(Select a Package)</option>
    <option value="149.00">PACKAGE A</option>
    <option value="223.00">PACKAGE B</option>
    <option value="273.00">PACKAGE C</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```